# Rename "Version comments" inside the document library's Upload.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library, versioning

When i open the `Upload.aspx` page for an online document library inside a new tab , i will get these fields:-

[image]

My question is if i can rename the "Version Comments" field? i access the document library fields and i can not find this field... can i rename it using PnP or other approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the "CheckinComment" field is not possible, as this is an internal SharePoint field.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but what do you mean by "Internal SharePoint field"

Comment: It is a field created for internal use by SharePoint itself. Here is a reference to CheckinComment in Microsoft's documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee538295(v=office.15)

If this answer was helpful, please let the community know by marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, under normal circumstances this field cannot be modified, it is managed by SharePoint directly.